# Constant gutter width between text and button in a card layout using material-ui

Tags: html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I have created a card which should act as a book cover. I am having trouble setting up a constant gutter between some text which has an id of text-div and a button which has an id of btn-div so that they cannot overlay on each other.

My code is in react and can be [viewed here](https://github.com/vamsiampolu/css-in-js-test/blob/glamor/app/Book.js). The inline styles are from [material-ui card](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/card) and the rest of the styles are generated using [glamor](https://github.com/threepointone/glamor)

I have extracted the generated html and css to a [codepen](http://codepen.io/vamsiampolu/pen/VmjQvo) as well as the snippet below.

You could use the [ghpages branch on my repo](https://vamsiampolu.github.io/css-in-js-test/) as well.

```css
.css-1wci4nz, [data-css-1wci4nz] {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    padding-right: 0.5rem;
    padding-left: 0.5rem;
    flex-grow: 0;
    flex-basis: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    margin-top: 2em;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-flex: 0 0 auto;
    -webkit-box-flex: 0;
    -webkit-flex-grow: 0;
    -ms-flex-positive: 0;
    -webkit-flex-basis: 0;
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 0;
    -webkit-flex-shrink: 0;
    -ms-flex-negative: 0;
}

.css-m2pnkn, [data-css-m2pnkn] {
    font-size: 12px;
    padding-left: 8px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 8px;
}

.css-1n54g2a, [data-css-1n54g2a] {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    padding-left: 8px;
    padding-right: 8px;
}

.css-n9jzlg, [data-css-n9jzlg] {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex: 0 1 auto;
    margin-right: -0.5rem;
    margin-left: -0.5rem;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    -webkit-flex: 0 1 auto;
    -webkit-box-flex: 0 1 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="css-n9jzlg">
  <div class="css-1wci4nz" data-css-1le4je3=":*" data-css-12vwhg5=":*">
    <div style="color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.870588); transition: all 450ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1) 0ms; box-sizing: border-box; font-family: Roboto, sans-serif; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.117647) 0px 1px 6px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.117647) 0px 1px 4px; border-radius: 2px; z-index: 1; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
      <div style="padding: 0px; height: 16em; position: relative;">
        <div style="padding: 8px; font-weight: 500; box-sizing: border-box; position: relative; white-space: nowrap;">
          <div style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; white-space: normal; padding-right: 0px;"><span style="color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.870588); display: block; font-size: 13px;">Programming JavaScript Applications</span><span style="color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.541176); display: block; font-size: 14px;"></span></div>
        </div><span class="css-m2pnkn">Eric Elliot</span>
        <div style="position: relative;">
          <div><img class="css-1n54g2a" src="http://lorempixel.com/200/100?t=1479180646864" alt="Placeholder image"></div>
          <!-- react-text: 103 -->
          <!-- /react-text -->
        </div>
        <div id="text-div" style="padding: 8px; font-size: 10px; color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.870588);">
          <div>
            <!-- react-text: 106 -->Nulla reprehenderit anim officia voluptate mollit laboris sit sunt dolore est laborum occaecat eiusmod fugiat. Anim officia laborum exercitation laborum nostrud quis voluptate exercitation in eu nisi.
            <!-- /react-text -->
            <!-- react-text: 107 -->
            <!-- /react-text -->
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="btn-div" style="padding: 0px; position: absolute; bottom: 0px; right: 0px; margin-top: 5px;"><button tabindex="0" type="button" style="border: 10px; box-sizing: border-box; display: inline-block; font-family: Roboto, sans-serif; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); cursor: pointer; text-decoration: none; margin: 0px 8px 0px 0px; padding: 0px; outline: none; font-size: inherit; font-weight: inherit; transform: translate(0px, 0px); height: 36px; line-height: 36px; min-width: 88px; color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.870588); transition: all 450ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1) 0ms; border-radius: 2px; position: relative; overflow: hidden; text-align: center; -webkit-user-select: none; background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"><div><span style="position: relative; padding-left: 16px; padding-right: 16px; vertical-align: middle; letter-spacing: 0px; text-transform: uppercase; font-weight: 500; font-size: 14px;">Buy Now</span></div></button></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your div that contains those two elements does not have enough height. How would you want them to layout?

Comment: with a constant space betweenn them regardless of generated lipsum text.

Comment: By expanding the box height? Or ellipsis overflow of the text?

Comment: I have ellipsis for over 300 charecters set up, but I want to make sure I get it working with a constant height between them for less than that.